# COPY в postgresql, ошибка: лишние данные после содержимого последнего столбца

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос

после запроса `COPY  objrts  FROM 'C:\objrt00100.unl' (DELIMITER '|');`
не знаю как бороться
`ОШИБКА:  лишние данные после содержимого последнего столбца
CONTEXT:  COPY objrts, строка 1: "11955|13124|I||93|0,0|0,0|0|0,0|0,0|0,0|0,0|0,0|0|0|2013-04-08 00:00:00|||"`

Comment: Посчитайте количество столбцов и количество делимитеров.
Возможно, стоит NULL написать между пустыми ||.

Answer (score 1):

Без структуры *objrts* точно ответ дать не получится, но вероятнее всего у вас в строке слишком много элементов. Попробуйте убрать несколько разделителей с конца.